# Throw error when I run in my shell script but run successfully in terminal console

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I am working on MacOS. Why can I run my command in the console and cannot run it in the shell?

The command is :

```
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fast "test.nii.gz"
```

The `/usr/local/fsl/bin/fast` is a software to preprocess the neuroimage.The official documentation is at [FAST docs](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FAST).

This is my shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fast "test.nii.gz"
```

This is the command in the terminal:

```
/usr/local/fsl/bin/fast "test.nii.gz"
```

They are exactly the same.
But the shell script throw an error like this:

```
/Users/weiziyang/study/Final_Project/code/auto-seg.sh: line 2:  9502 Segmentation fault: 11  /usr/local/fsl/bin/fast "test.nii.gz"
```

I want it run successfuly!

Comment: Your `fast` binary is probably using some environment variable. A regular terminal is running as you, with your environment. A console may be running as root or some other user. Use `env` to print the environment in each shell and compare them.

Comment: Other possibility is the shebang of your script is `#!/bin/sh` and not `#!/usr/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. `/bin/sh` may be running ksh or some POSIX only or restricted shell, whereas your terminal session runs a Bash shell.

Comment: @GaryO If it is the problem with the `env`, how to solve it ?

Comment: If the shell where it's missing the env is the one where it's crashing, then do `export VAR=proper-value` to set the var. Then it shouldn't crash.

Comment: @LéaGris : Looking at the shell script posted, it is so simple that it doesn't matter wheather it is executed by sh, bash or whatever. It would even be equivalent under csh.

Comment: @Weiziyoung : A correct program is certainly not supposed to run on a SEGV. It might be an uninitialized pointer inside the program, which by chance does not harm sometimes, but bites you when the memory is set up in a certain way. I would report this as a bug to the `fast` developers.

Comment: @GaryO fine, i copy the `env` value to the bash script with adding `export` to them.Now it's ok!

Answer (score 1):

(pasted from comment that turned out to be the right guess) 
Your fast binary is probably using some environment variable. A regular terminal is running as you, with your environment. A console may be running as root or some other user. Use env to print the environment in each shell and compare them.